# What is an AVP? What do they do?

Tags: terminology

I recently received an email from a company member whose job title was listed as AVP.

From what I can tell, it sounds like this person is coming from a place of authority, but I'm not sure what the job title actually means.

What does AVP stand for? What does an AVP do?

Comment: Associate/Assitant Vice President

Comment: @GrayCygnus probably, but who could say for sure.

Comment: Aliens vs Predator.  Obvious really....

Comment: @SaggingRufus yes indeed, it could also be Acrobatic Vortex Positioner

Comment: have you asked them?

Comment: Anthill, Very Perplexing

Comment: Have you tried asking a coworker? Looking at your company's website or intranet? This is really a company specific question - there is no global standard for job title abbreviations, much less their job responsibilities. GrayCygnus's answer is probably correct, but there's no way we can know for sure.

Comment: Amazing Virtual Person?

Comment: Apple Versus Pear

Comment: Any Variable, Perhaps?

Comment: These comments are All Very Persuasive

Comment: Or is it Assistant *to* the Vice President...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *could* mean, **Assistance or Associate Vice President** (source: quick google search).

From the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice_president):

> When there are several vice presidents in a company, these individuals are sometimes **differentiated with titles** denoting higher positions such as executive vice president and/or senior vice president with the remaining management team holding the title vice president. The title of *assistant vice president* or *associate vice president* is used in large organizations below vice president.

Comment: Exactly how "high" the position is depends greatly on the organization and industry. The joke in banking is that an AVP is an entry-level position.

Comment: @mcknz when I was working at a certain financial company, AVP was literally one step above entry level, so I KNOW that's true.